# Getting files from AWS codecommit

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-codecommit

I have a file on codecommit with the uri:

```
codecommit://FruitLoops/apples/granny_smith.json
```

And when I tried:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.session(some_key, some_secret, key)

repo = "FruitLoops"

client.get_file(repositoryName="FruitLoops", filePath="apples/granny_smith.json"
```

It's throwing an error:L

```
RepositoryDoesNotExistException: An error ocurred (RepositoryDoesNotExistException) when calling GetFile operation on: FruitLoops does not exist
```

I've tried searching around on Google and found the example https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2329 and https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codecommit.html

But when I used the CLI, the repository is there

```
aws codecommit get-file --repository-name FruitLoops --file-path "apples/granny_smith.json" --query fileContent --output text
```

**What is the right syntax in `boto3` to access the file through codecommit?**

Comment: The syntax is correct. I would check that the boto3 client initialized is correct with keys that have access to the repo

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the region name. Here is the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) which explains how you can do that.